# Typo3 10.4 Clear cache in Backend throws error: "An error occurred while cleaning the cache" - how to debug?

Tags: caching, typo3, backend

Clear cache in BE throws error: "An error occurred while cleaning the cache".
I get no error in the logs, neither in Typo3 BE nor on server side - how can I debug this?

In the maintenance tools I already:

- Flushed TYPO3 and PHP Cache
- Analyzed Database Structure
- Removed Temporary Assets
- Clear Persistent Database Tables

I deleted manually all files and folders in typo3temp/var/cache/code and typo3temp/var/cache/data. Also updated reference index. Still same error:

[screenshot of error message when trying to clean cashes via Typo3 BE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rXwgV.png)

Version: Typo3 10.4.20
PHP Version 7.4.25

Comment: Did you check the log in `typo3temp/var/log`?

Comment: yes, unfortunately there is no new entry written in the logs when the error is thrown.

Comment: the weired thing is, that in the maintanance module the "Flush TYPO3 and PHP Cache" allegedly does the same as the "Flush all caches" in the header (via the lightning icon), but the first works, the second is throwing the error. Updated on typo3 10.4.21 - still same issue.

Comment: Please look in Developer Tools console (e.g. F12) AND in logs of logging framework. This is an error message in JavaScript (Ajax). It may help to look in the Console or Network tab of Developer tools. Also might help to debug. But it is weird you get this. Never seen this behaviour (that works in maintenance and not in topbar).

Comment: one step forward: did not see any suspicious messages in console or network in dev tools (only a warning: "Cookie “fe_typo_user” will be soon treated as cross-site cookie), but tested it in chrome again and got the "Allow notifications" message that I agreed to, but possibly I did not agree long time ago, that may had impact on this. Because since then clearing the cache terminiates fast without an error message, although also without a success messsage :). Same Behaviour in FF and Chrome. In maintenance I get an success message. Anyway thx for debug suggests!

Comment: Had exactly the same error and found out it was caused by a router using security filters that blocked the request https://example.com/typo3/index.php?route=/record/commit&token=XXX&cacheCmd=all with http status code 403.

Answer (score 0):

Its certainly a long time and this issue might be a different one BUT:
Today I was doing a migration and `defined('TYPO3_MODE') or die();` caused my cache to not work and to display this message.
after I swapped it with `defined('TYPO3') or die();` it worked.
After this I'd actually suggest to not use `die()` but rather a simple `throw new Exception('TYPO3 is not defined')`.
It seem safer and less radical